# Php doesn't display special characters

Tags: php, joomla-3.3.x

I have a .php that retrieves the publish_up field and echo it. But it doesn't display the special characters such as é,è,û... Instead I get a `�`. I have set this `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"` but it doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    
    </head>
<body>
      <?php                                 
      $oldLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_US');
      echo strftime("%a %d %b %Y", strtotime($jitem1->publish_up)); 
      setlocale(LC_TIME, $oldLocale);
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be due to the encoding of the file. You can set encoding to `UTF-8` by a good text editor like Notepad++ or by command line. For exmaple in *nix OS's:

```
iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 "test.php" -o "utf8.test.php"
```

### Update 1

Also it could be due to your MySql encoding. You can add these lines before executing a query (in your model):

```
$jdb1->execute("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$jdb1->execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$jdb1->execute("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'latin1_general_ci'");
```

`$jdb1` is your JDatabase instance.

### Update 2

[If strange characters are returned use `utf8_encode(strftime())` for UTF-8 characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#104043)

Comment: Thanks Fari! I have tried the updated solution but it's not working. I forgot to mention that my query also retrieves the  `introtext ` field in which I have special characters. The special characters in  `introtext ` are correctly displayed, I only have a problem with the one in publish_up. So I guess, that can't be due to the encoding of the file.

Comment: According to your description, you can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993971/php-strftime-french-characters). Use `utf8_encode();`.

Comment: This last link was the good one! Thanks so much Fari!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the correct character encoding set on your database. 
To find out, check the collation used in the database for publish_up.  The correct collation to use depends on what language your website uses, but in general utf8_general_ci will work for most English language websites (apparently utf8_general_ci  [doesn't properly support all UTF8 coding](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) , so if your version of mysql supports it you might want to use utf8mb4 instead.)

To check the database, I recommend using a program such as phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thanks moomoochoo! I have try to set the the publish_up collation to `utf8_general_ci`  (same collation I used for `introtext` in which I have special characters) but the database seems to not be able to process the change. Is it because the field type is `DATETIME` (instead of `mediumtext` for `introtex`)? I am afraid I can't change the field type for `publish_up` to `mediumtext` without seriously interfering with  the Joomla structure.

Comment: I forgot to mention:  `publish_up ` collation is empty

Comment: OK. I wouldn't change the field type. I'd glossed over the fact that you are using DATETIME for publish_up, so my solution isn't helpful in your case. I think that Fari's link is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Fari's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993971/php-strftime-french-characters) (Update 2) here is the solution:

```
<?php $oldLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');
$date_string = utf8_encode(strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($jitem1->publish_up)));
echo $date_string;
setlocale(LC_TIME, $oldLocale); 
?>
```